# 200 TextFields with validation in GridLayout optimization

Tags: vaadin, vaadin6

I have grid layout with around 200 textfields with validation in a grid layout and it takes around ~20s to render UI.

Any workaround for this. Please provide your suggestion

Comment: What have you found out yourself so far? -- edit: All of your questions lack research. Suggestions like "Please do the needful." are brash at best.

Comment: @phresnel : I have tired gzip compression in tomcat for css, html, json but still the loading of UI takes 20 sec to display 200 textfields in grid layout

Comment: When i inspect the page with firebug the content size is just 50kb

Comment: Server visit took 6027ms
JSON parsing took 8ms
Processing time was 25223ms for 101518 characters of JSON
Referenced paintables: 861

Comment: It's one of the main problems in Vaadin 6, it does a lot of div nesting, which then gives very poor UI rendering performance when you have a lot of items.
The rendertime is then, when your webbrowser has finished "Turning the Vaddin busy indicator" and just freezes before you can interact again with the webbrowser.
Try reducing the number of generated div is the sole hope

Comment: Try a table instead of a GridLayout, this supports lazy loading for the client (at least in vaadin 7).